# Angular Template Reference : Bind height of one div to height of another

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I want to bind the height of one angular component to the height of a div. I am trying to use template reference to fetch the height.

Is it possible to do so using this method in a clean way? I want to do it something like this in snippet below.

```
<div [style.height.px]="section1.offsetHeight"></div>
<app-custom-tag #section1>
</app-custom-tag>
```

I want the height of `<div>` to be equal to height of `<app-custom-tag>`

I can't use css column layout for this as these two elements are not positioned together.

Comment: Did you confuse `java` with `javascript`?

Comment: What do you mean? @Turing85

Comment: The `java` tag in the [first revision of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59595124/1).

Comment: oops! my bad. It's javascript.

Comment: What do you get when you try the code in your question?

Comment: I get the two divs, but the divs are not aligned as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a few extra things you'll have to do.

When you **reference** a **component** inside the view, you'll get the **class instance**. With that in mind, you can inject the `ElementRef` so you can get information about the **native element**.

Consider this example:

#### foo.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  template: `foo`,
  styles: [`:host { color: red; display: block; height: 300px; } `]
})
export class FooComp {

  get offsetHeight () {
    return this.el.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
  }

  constructor (private el: ElementRef) { }
}
```

#### app.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
template: `
  <foo #f></foo> 
  {{ f.offsetHeight }}

  <br>

  <div style="border: 1px solid black" [style.height.px]="f.offsetHeight"></div>
  <!-- <div style="border: 1px solid black" [ngStyle]="{ height: f.offsetHeight + 'px' }"></div> -->

  <br>

  <input #i id="demo" type="text">

  {{ i.id }}
`,
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

When you reference a DOM element in the view, you'll get that DOM element.

[ng-run demo](https://ng-run.com/edit/cUmZrYjtXINnnZoxWHEO).